# DRY and Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, dry

I have a model with 3 attachements, please, help me to DRY.

```
class Somename < ActiveRecord::Base

has_attached_file :picture, :url => "/uploads/p/:id/picture.:extension"
validates_attachment_presence :picture
validates_attachment_content_type :picture, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']

has_attached_file :another_picture, :url => "/uploads/p/:id/another_pictures/:style/another_picture.:extension",
    :styles => { main: '720x480#', small: '480x311#' }
validates_attachment_presence :another_picture
validates_attachment_content_type :another_picture, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']

has_attached_file :last_one, :url => "/uploads/p/:id/last_one.:extension"
validates_attachment_presence :last_one
validates_attachment_content_type :last_one, :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']
end
```

Especially validates. Why i cant do something like this:

```
validates_attachment_presence :picture, :another_picture, :last_one
```

?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this (not sure if it will work exactly as-is with Paperclip, but likely should work fine) :

(see the [source code of `validates_attachment_presence`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip.rb#L387) and it will be clearer whats going on)

```
module PaperclipEnhancement
  def validates_attachments_presence(*attributes) # note the plural 'attachments'
    attributes.each do |attribute|
      validates_attachment_presence attribute #call the original paperclip validator
    end
  end  
end

class Somename < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend PaperclipEnhancement
  validates_attachments_presence :picture1, :picture2
end
```